# Control not coming back to Subscriber in Rx Android, get a blank screen

Tags: java, android, rx-java, observable, rx-android

My Api interface:

```
public interface LodgingApi {

@GET("LodgingBoarding/GetLogingBoardingSetup")
Observable<LodgingBoardingSetupResponse> getSetupResponse(
        @Header("Authorization") String authKey,
        @Header("X-User-Id-1") String profileId
);
...

}
```

My controller where I Subscribe to the Observable:

```
public class LodgingBoardingRequestController extends BaseController<LodgingRequestFragmentListener> {

private LodgingApi lodgingApi;
private LoginResponse loginResponse;

public LodgingBoardingRequestController(@NonNull Context applicationContext,
                                        @NonNull LodgingRequestFragmentListener viewListener) {
    super(applicationContext, viewListener);
    lodgingApi = ApiCreator.instance().create(LodgingApi.class);
    loginResponse = new LoginPreference(getApplicationContext()).read();
}

public void getLodgingSetup() {
    String authKey = loginResponse.getAuthKey();
    String profileId = loginResponse.getProfileId();

    Observable<LodgingBoardingSetupResponse> setupResponse = lodgingApi.getSetupResponse(authKey, profileId);

    setupResponse.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new Observer<LodgingBoardingSetupResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                    getViewListener().showToast("on subscribe");
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(LodgingBoardingSetupResponse response) {
                    getViewListener().showToast("on next");
                    getViewListener().onGetLodgingSetupResponseSuccess(response);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    getViewListener().showToast("on error");
                    getViewListener().onGetLodgingSetupResponseFailure("Network or Server Error", e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    getViewListener().showToast("on complete");
                }
            });
}


...
}
```

Thereafter I want to use the response "LodgingBoardingSetupResponse" to update my UI in a Fragment class using listener.

How ever when i run this, the control doesn't come to the Subscriber's OnNext() method and i get a blank page which also disappears in some time and goes back to previous screen.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: i know this is not answer, why use "Controller" terminology (LodgingBoardingRequestController extends BaseController) here in android, that is related to IOS . Call it as LodgingBoardingRequestActivity extends BaseActivity

Comment: You can output log reports in the observer chain: `.doOnNext( val -> Log.v( "next: " + val) )`. Similarly with `.doOnError()` and `.doOnComplete()`. Put them before and after your `observeOn()` and `subscribeOn()` operators to see if something is getting lost.